# How can I extract video ID from YouTube's link in Python?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, url-parsing

I know this can be easily done using PHP's `parse_url` and `parse_str` functions:

```
$subject = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_AbfPXTKms&NR=1";
$url = parse_url($subject);
parse_str($url['query'], $query);
var_dump($query);
```

But how to achieve this using Python? I can do `urlparse` but what next?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Python has [a library for parsing URLs](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

```
import urlparse
url_data = urlparse.urlparse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_AbfPXTKms&NR=1")
query = urlparse.parse_qs(url_data.query)
video = query["v"][0]
```

Comment: `I can do urlparse but what next?` yeah I know, but problem is with the query part.

Comment: @decarbo The updated answer shows you how to extract just the value of the `v` parameter in the query string.

Comment: yap, that's the best solution I guess.

Comment: FYI this will not work when submitting `youtube.com/watch?v=hP54ne1COvY` because its missing the http

Comment: please note `urlparse` was moved to `urllib.parse` in Python3

Something along the lines of this would do the trick:
`import urllib.parse as urlparse`

Answer (score 65):

I've created youtube id parser without regexp:

```py
import urlparse

def video_id(value):
    """
    Examples:
    - http://youtu.be/SA2iWivDJiE
    - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oPAwA_Udwc&feature=feedu
    - http://www.youtube.com/embed/SA2iWivDJiE
    - http://www.youtube.com/v/SA2iWivDJiE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US
    """
    query = urlparse.urlparse(value)
    if query.hostname == 'youtu.be':
        return query.path[1:]
    if query.hostname in ('www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com'):
        if query.path == '/watch':
            p = urlparse.parse_qs(query.query)
            return p['v'][0]
        if query.path[:7] == '/embed/':
            return query.path.split('/')[2]
        if query.path[:3] == '/v/':
            return query.path.split('/')[2]
    # fail?
    return None
```

Comment: This one is great for parsing all of the possible youtube link formats.

Comment: you can use `query.path.startswith('/embed/')` for added legibility.

Comment: The above solution works well except for one scenario.

https://m.youtube.com/?#/watch?v=683hzaj3oc8

It would be  really helpful if I get solution for the above scenario also.

Comment: "i will finish what you started" ;) :: https://gist.github.com/kmonsoor/2a1afba4ee127cce50a0

Comment: Out of date (for me in python3.11)

Answer (score 15):

This is the Python3 version of Mikhail Kashkin's solution with added scenarios.

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
from contextlib import suppress


# noinspection PyTypeChecker
def get_yt_id(url, ignore_playlist=False):
    # Examples:
    # - http://youtu.be/SA2iWivDJiE
    # - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oPAwA_Udwc&feature=feedu
    # - http://www.youtube.com/embed/SA2iWivDJiE
    # - http://www.youtube.com/v/SA2iWivDJiE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US
    query = urlparse(url)
    if query.hostname == 'youtu.be': return query.path[1:]
    if query.hostname in {'www.youtube.com', 'youtube.com', 'music.youtube.com'}:
        if not ignore_playlist:
        # use case: get playlist id not current video in playlist
            with suppress(KeyError):
                return parse_qs(query.query)['list'][0]
        if query.path == '/watch': return parse_qs(query.query)['v'][0]
        if query.path[:7] == '/watch/': return query.path.split('/')[2]
        if query.path[:7] == '/embed/': return query.path.split('/')[2]
        if query.path[:3] == '/v/': return query.path.split('/')[2]
   # returns None for invalid YouTube url

# unit test
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'url,expected_id',
    (
        ('https://youtu.be/Dlxu28sQfkE', 'Dlxu28sQfkE'),
        ('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dlxu28sQfkE&feature=youtu.be', 'Dlxu28sQfkE'),
        ('https://www.youtube.com/watch/Dlxu28sQfkE', 'Dlxu28sQfkE'),
        ('https://www.youtube.com/embed/Dlxu28sQfkE', 'Dlxu28sQfkE'),
        ('https://www.youtube.com/v/Dlxu28sQfkE', 'Dlxu28sQfkE'),
        ('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRbcUrcJVEmX_eaAsubNOWfE4SlhGqjW4', 'PLRbcUrcJVEmX_eaAsubNOWfE4SlhGqjW4'),
    ),
)
def test_yt_id(url, expected_id):
    assert get_yt_id(url) == expected_id
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is RegExp it cover these cases [image]

`((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\?|\&)v=)|(?<=embed/))([\w-]+)`

Comment: to get this to work in python, i had to correct the syntax too: `((?<=(v|V)/)|(?<=be/)|(?<=(\?|\&)v=)|(?<=embed/))([\w-]+)`.
This solution ended up being the one that handled the most cases.

Comment: `/((?<=(v|e|V|vi)\/)|(?<=be\/)|(?<=(\?|\&)v=)|(?<=\/u\/\d+\/)|(?<=(\?|\&)vi=)|(?<=embed\/))([\w-]+)/gi;`

Compatible with most at https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486

Answer (score 6):

I use this great package [`pytube`](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/).`$ pip install pytube`

```py
#Examples
url1='http://youtu.be/SA2iWivDJiE'
url2='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oPAwA_Udwc&feature=feedu'
url3='http://www.youtube.com/embed/SA2iWivDJiE'
url4='http://www.youtube.com/v/SA2iWivDJiE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US'
url5='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTHlyTphWP0&index=6&list=PLjeDyYvG6-40qawYNR4juzvSOg-ezZ2a6'
url6='youtube.com/watch?v=_lOT2p_FCvA'
url7='youtu.be/watch?v=_lOT2p_FCvA'
url8='https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=9&v=n0g-Y0oo5Qs&feature=emb_logo'

urls=[url1,url2,url3,url4,url5,url6,url7,url8]

#Get youtube id
from pytube import extract
for url in urls:
    id=extract.video_id(url)
    print(id)
```

**Output**

```sh
SA2iWivDJiE
_oPAwA_Udwc
SA2iWivDJiE
SA2iWivDJiE
rTHlyTphWP0
_lOT2p_FCvA
_lOT2p_FCvA
n0g-Y0oo5Qs
```

Comment: this is the best answer by far, as it accounts for all url types. none of the other answers do

Comment: It's a very good idea to use a library for this, but at the end it uses a regex, and a very simple one https://github.com/pytube/pytube/blob/master/pytube/extract.py#L118

Answer (score 4):

```
match = re.search(r"youtube\.com/.*v=([^&]*)", "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_AbfPXTKms&test=123")
if match:
    result = match.group(1)
else:
    result = ""
```

Untested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

url_data = urlparse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG9TMn1FJzc")
print(url_data.query[2::])
```

Answer (score 3):

Splitting strings is a really bad idea when those parameters could come in any order. Stick with urlparse:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

vid = parse_qs(urlparse(url).query).get('v')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you could try using regex for the youtube video ID:

```
# regex for the YouTube ID: "^[^v]+v=(.{11}).*"
result = re.match('^[^v]+v=(.{11}).*', url)
print result.group(1)
```

Comment: This answer is from 2010, but the regex can be modified to match this pattern too.
`be[/](.{11}).*`

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex. Split on `?`, take the second, split on `=`, take the second, split on `&`, take the first.

Comment: work. Do you have any idea if this method is bulletproof enough to be used without bigger worries in market-ready projects ?

Comment: use urlparse for this.  don't roll your own with string splitting or regexes. http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html

Comment: urlparse gives query as a whole so still I need to split it to get ID

Answer (score 0):

Although this will take a search query but gives you the `id`:

```
from youtube_search import YoutubeSearch    
results = YoutubeSearch('search terms', max_results=10).to_json()    
print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_AbfPXTKms&NR=1"
parsed = url.split("?")
videoId = parsed[1]
print(videoId)
```

This will work for all kinds of YouTube video links.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late, but I use this snippet to get the video id.

```
def video_id(url: str) -> str:
    """Extract the ``video_id`` from a YouTube url.
    This function supports the following patterns:
    - :samp:`https://youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}`
    - :samp:`https://youtube.com/embed/{video_id}`
    - :samp:`https://youtu.be/{video_id}`
    :param str url:
        A YouTube url containing a video id.
    :rtype: str
    :returns:
        YouTube video id.
    """
    return regex_search(r"(?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*", url, group=1)

def regex_search(pattern: str, string: str, group: int):
    """Shortcut method to search a string for a given pattern.
    :param str pattern:
        A regular expression pattern.
    :param str string:
        A target string to search.
    :param int group:
        Index of group to return.
    :rtype:
        str or tuple
    :returns:
        Substring pattern matches.
    """
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    results = regex.search(string)
    if not results:
        return False

    return results.group(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
def getId(videourl):
    vidid=videourl.find('watch?v=')
    Id = videourl[vidid+8:vidid+19]
    if vidid==-1:
        vidid=videourl.find('be/')
        Id=videourl[vidid+3:]
    return Id
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).